# R dplyr: converting cut-and paste to a calling function

Tags: r, dplyr, functional-programming

My code is almost finished I need 3-year running totals. I need the running totals by various groupings. I need a function.

I can compute the numerator and the denominator.

I need to join the data frame from the numerator computation to the data frame from the denominator computation. I do not know how to do that.

So the only remaining step is obtaining a syntactically correct *by* clause.

My partial solution is below.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(slider)  # for grouping consecutive years


# The sample data
set.seed(2021)

EVENT_YEAR = 2010:2015
RE = c('white', 'black', 'Asian')
City = c('Oakland', 'San Francisco', 'San Jose')
Note = 1:3

# data frame for numerator
demoDF_N = expand.grid(EVENT_YEAR = EVENT_YEAR, RE = RE, City = City, Note = Note)
demoDF_N$Numerator = sample(3:10, 162, replace = TRUE)
demoDF_N$EVENT_YEAR = as.factor(demoDF_N$EVENT_YEAR)
demoDF_N$RE = as.factor(demoDF_N$RE)
demoDF_N$City = as.factor(demoDF_N$City)
demoDF_N$Note = as.factor(demoDF_N$Note)
demoDF_D$EVENT_YEAR = as.factor(demoDF_D$EVENT_YEAR)

# data frame for denominator
demoDF_D = expand.grid(EVENT_YEAR = EVENT_YEAR, RE = RE, City = City, Note = Note)
demoDF_D$Denominator = sample(90:120, 162, replace = TRUE) 


func1 = function(df1, df2, groups){ 
  result_3_N = df1 %>%    
    group_by(Note, across({{groups}})) %>%               
    arrange(Note, across({{groups}}), EVENT_YEAR) %>%
    mutate(Numerator_UPDATED = slide_dbl(Numerator, sum, .before = 1, .after = 1, 
                                         .complete = TRUE)) %>%
    select(Note, {{groups}}, EVENT_YEAR, Numerator_UPDATED) %>% 
    ungroup()
  result_3_N = result_3_N %>% rename(Numerator = Numerator_UPDATED) # simple rename
  
  result_3_N = result_3_N %>% filter(!is.na(Numerator))  # filter out rows not based on 3 full years
  
  # Get EVENT_YEAR to display range of years, e.g., 2008-2010
  result_3_N$EVENT_YEAR = 
    paste(as.integer(as.character(result_3_N$EVENT_YEAR)) - 1, '-', 
          as.integer(as.character(result_3_N$EVENT_YEAR)) + 1, sep = '')
  
  ###
  result_3_D = df2 %>%    
    group_by(Note, across({{groups}})) %>%               
    arrange(Note, across({{groups}}), EVENT_YEAR) %>%
    mutate(Denominator_UPDATED = slide_dbl(Denominator, sum, .before = 1, .after = 1, 
                                         .complete = TRUE)) %>%
    select(Note, {{groups}}, EVENT_YEAR, Denominator_UPDATED) %>% 
    ungroup()
  result_3_D = result_3_D %>% rename(Denominator = Denominator_UPDATED) # simple rename
  
  result_3_D = result_3_D %>% filter(!is.na(Denominator))  # filter out rows not based on 3 full years
  
  # Get EVENT_YEAR to display range of years, e.g., 2008-2010
  result_3_D$EVENT_YEAR = 
    paste(as.integer(as.character(result_3_D$EVENT_YEAR)) - 1, '-', 
          as.integer(as.character(result_3_D$EVENT_YEAR)) + 1, sep = '')
  
  # Trying to join the results; INCORRECT: by = c(groups))
  # result3 = result_3_N %>% right_join(result_3_D, by = c(groups)) %>%
  #   replace_na(list(Denominator = 0)) %>% replace_na(list(Numerator = 0))
  
  
  result3
}
```

A few calls

```
res1 = func1(demoDF_N, demoDF_D, EVENT_YEAR)
res1

res2 = func1(demoDF_N, demoDF_D, c(EVENT_YEAR, RE))
res2
```

Comment: This is a lot to digest. Can you provide example code that minimally reproduces your problem? It would also be extremely helpful to have a sample of the input data and the intended output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

The first grouping of code is my dataset demoDF.

I then show four of the calls I would like to make.

Then func_3() is the function where I am having a problem. I have spent days on this function. The code after func_3() are just examples of working interactive code. 
I do not know how to use parameters in this setting.

I have looked at Hadley’s Advanced R but it is not helping.

Comment: Can you please shorten the question? Which is the specific part that isn't working as desired?

Comment: I shortened the question. In multiple places parameters need to be inserted. I inserted # This is the function that needs fixing
# group_by(what do I put in here?)
# arrange(what do I put in here?)
# mutate(what do I put in here?)
# select(what do I put in here?) Also in the join, I need to put something in by()

Comment: @user2738483 your question is still very unclear. The title gives no information at all and there is no real question. I ran your code with no error and the output made sense. You ask for the "three year running totals" but your code refers to the "3-year running average". What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the 3-y running average, then you need to use the  `mean` function inside `slider::slide_dbl()`.

If you only want the average running on the YEAR, then you will have to group on any other variable. Beware that your dataset should be complete, i.e. every YEAR should be present (it can be NA though). Else, the running average might be wrong.

Here is the code:

```r
df1 %>% 
  group_by(RE, City, Note) %>% 
  arrange(EVENT_YEAR) %>% 
  mutate(Numerator_UPDATED = zoo::rollmean(Numerator, 3, fill=NA), 
         Numerator_UPDATED2 = slider::slide_dbl(Numerator, mean, .before = 1, .after = 1, .complete = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(Note, City, RE, EVENT_YEAR)

# # A tibble: 162 x 7
# # Groups:   RE, City, Note [27] 
#   EVENT_YEAR RE    City     Note Numerator Numerator_UPDATED Numerator_UPDATED2
#        <int> <fct> <fct>   <int>     <int>             <dbl>              <dbl>
# 1       2010 white Oakland     1         9             NA                 NA   
# 2       2011 white Oakland     1         8              8.33               8.33
# 3       2012 white Oakland     1         8              6.67               6.67
# 4       2013 white Oakland     1         4              7                  7   
# 5       2014 white Oakland     1         9              6.33               6.33
# 6       2015 white Oakland     1         6             NA                 NA   
# 7       2010 black Oakland     1         6             NA                 NA   
# 8       2011 black Oakland     1         8              8                  8   
# 9       2012 black Oakland     1        10              8.67               8.67
# 10      2013 black Oakland     1         8              7.67               7.67
```